# Best Practice Transition from Older iPad

Tags: ipad

An older iPad Air (iOS 12.5.4), Model MD796LL/A will be retired in favor of a 2021 iPad Pro.

I am able to back the Air to a Catalina Mac. Is it possible to restore the backup to the 2021 Pro?

Is the best practice to "start from scratch" (install the Apps from the App Store manually to mirror the iPad Air)?

Any [migration](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201269) best practices are appreciated.

An attempt to "Transfer data directly from one iPhone or iPad to another", via [Quickstart](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216) failed at step 5:

> Tap Transfer from [Device] to begin transferring your data from your
> previous iPhone or iPad to your new device. If you're using the wired
> method, the transfer icon  indicates that your devices are connected.
> You can also choose whether to transfer some settings, such as Apple
> Pay and Siri, from your previous device to your new iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve also had many issues with Quick Transfer. I’ve found that iCloud or Mac transfer works just as well. Could you try iCloud backup & restore? I heard they were giving unlimited storage if you are trying to restore via iCloud. If that doesn’t work or you’d prefer not to upload and download a few GB, take a backup to your Mac and restore it to the new iPad. I would NOT recommend starting from scratch unless you feel that your current iPad is cluttered and you WANT to start from scratch. Starting from scratch is almost never necessary on a fully functional (old) iPad.